# How to hint which overridden function to pass as a parameter in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm building a basic calculator in Swift for Stanford's Swift MOOC.

I have a switch statement into which I'm passing infix arithmetic operations (as logic attached to a button press):

```
 let operation = sender.currentTitle!
        var op_result = false
        switch operation {
        case "+": op_result = performOperation( + )
        case "−": op_result = performOperation( - )
        case "×": op_result = performOperation( * )
        case "÷": op_result = performOperation( / )

        default:
            break
        }
```

This feeds into a function with the signature:
`func performOperation (op: (Double, Double) -> Double) -> Bool`

The above code worked fine - until I started trying to add a square root (single parameter) operation. I added an overridden performOperation function:

`func performOperation (op: (Double) -> Double) -> Bool`

As soon as this overridden function was present, I began to get an error for the plus and minus cases only above: "Double is not a subtype of UInt8"

My guess is that the type inference logic is seeing the single parameter performOperation variant and is assuming I want the unary operators instead, but I'm not sure.

How can I debug this issue or, if my guess about the cause is correct, hint to the system that I want the two-argument infix operator?

Comment: I'd say it feels more like you're trying to combine a UInt8 with a Double somewhere in your code. The function signature is correct, what's wrong lies in the implementation of your code.

Comment: I'd agree if it didn't work perfectly when the performOperation function isn't overloaded. All of the arguments being passed into the function are Doubles. Additionally, the problem doesn't present for the multiply and division operations, presumably because they don't have unary variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *why* the compiler doesn't handle this, but to work around the issue you can explicitly tell the it to use the `Double` version of `+`:

```
func f (op: (Double, Double) -> Double) -> () {

}

func f (op: Double -> Double) -> () {

}

let g: (Double, Double) -> Double = (+)
f(g)
```

Comment: This works, but it feels a bit strange. I'm certainly sacrificing the brevity I was looking for with the switch at that point, and I wonder if it wouldn't be better to just pass the whole thing as a closure?

Comment: You could use different names for the functions. E.g. `performUnaryOperation`, `performBinaryOperation`, etc

Comment: That's true, probably even preferable to wrapping the operator in a function just to disambiguate. What about passing { $0 + $1 } instead of just the operator?